# Docker container disappears

Tags: docker, visual-studio, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am following a tutorial and within `Visual Studio 2022` i create a `Dockerfile` for the current  project.

I assume the Dockerfile i created is correct as after i run the initial command i see the Image created. I see this under `Docker Desktop > Images`

Following on the tutorial, the below command should create a Container

```
docker run --rm -d -p 1234:80 --name testOne u9 --env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
```

Running the above command displays a long string of characters (suggesting it ran successfully i assume). In docker Desktop i see the container section and i notice a new entry

```
testone
```

A few seconds later, it disappears. I cant access it or view it in a browser or anything.

I then tried to get the logs to see what is going on but running the `docker -logs` command returns the container does not exist.

Can anyone advise what i could attempt to get a container running successfully?

Comment: Your container is removed after exit. Remove the --rm args for running and check your logs docker logs testone

Comment: In that `docker run` line, `u9` is the image name, and `--env ...` after it is the command to run.  Do you need to put the `--env` option before the image name?  If you remove the `-d` option to run the container in the foreground, does it print out a useful error?

Comment: In the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ the --env is an option and must be set before the container name. You can remove the -d option for the logs it depends on your image, you can check info with docker logs testone

Comment: @MoiioM Thanks removing the --rm led me to the underlying error message. Feel free to add it as an answer and i will mark as so